# Slide through words with jQuery/jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a sentence with an emphasized word. This emphasized word shall disappear by sliding up and being replaced by another word that slides up as well. I tried using jQuery (edge) and jQuery UI 1.8.9 like this ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15yazgsa/)) but can't get it to run:

HTML

```
<p>This is my text
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
    <span>four</span>
    <span>five</span>
without fear.</p>
```

CSS

```
span {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
span:first-child {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    var first = $('span:first-child');
    replaceWord(first);
});

function replaceWord(word) {
    var next = word.next();
    if (typeof(next) != "undefined") {
        first.hide("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 500, function () {
            next.show("slide", {
                direction: "down"
            }, 1000);
            replaceWord(next);
        });
    }
}
```

To get a feeling for what I'm looking for: I managed to get this effect, but not calling the function recursively and with jQuery 1.9.1/jQuery UI 1.9.2 [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntsg5uhd/). And this has a CSS bug so that it applies `display: block` while animating.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using float:left seems to work...

http://jsfiddle.net/apcwonn7/2/

```
<p><span>This is my text</span>
    <span class='a'>one</span>
    <span class='b'>two</span>
without fear.</p>
<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('span.a').show();
});

$('#go').click(function () {
    var first = $('span.a');
    var next = $('span.b');
    console.log(first, next);
    first.hide("slide", {
        direction: "up"
    }, 500, function () {
        next.show("slide", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
span {
    float: left;
}

span.a {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}

span.b {
    display: none;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I've been playing with the answers and thought it might be helpful to post it here http://jsfiddle.net/apcwonn7/3/

Comment: @jt000 Your fiddle example doesn't work. Click on button doesn't do anything.

Comment: @jt000 You need to change the URL to HTTP not HTTPS to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code corrected (still not the good result but it's working now) :

JS :

```
$(function () {
   var first = $('span:first-child')[0]; //It's an array
   replaceWord(first);
});

function replaceWord(word) {
var next = $(word).next(); //next is a jQuery func
if (typeof(next) != "undefined") {
    $(word).hide("slide", { //same with hide
        direction: "up"
    }, 500, function () {
        $(next).show("slide", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 1000);
        replaceWord(next);
    });
  }
}
```